# Assigning Values to Third Column Based on Values in First Two Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Like most people, we use excel for some reporting outside of our normal system depending upon what management wants to know.

Many of the projects we do receive funding from multiple sources - a common question is, if a project receives any funding from a funding source, what are the associated costs and how does this compare with other funding sources assigned to that project.

We do most of this with formula, and should be simple, but having trouble with a basic step to assign projects to a program.

All I want to do for this step is populate a column based on the values in the first two.

As a simple example, if the values in the first two columns were:

| Project | Funding |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NW |
| 1 | NW |
| 1 | WS |
| 2 | WS |
| 2 | WS |
| 2 | WS |
| 3 | NW |
| 3 | NW |
| 3 | AR |
| 4 | AR |
| 4 | AR |
| 4 | WS |

And we wanted to develop the data for developing a report involving funding from NW we would want a third column to be populated with values like this:

| Project | Funding | Program |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NW | NW |
| 1 | NW | NW |
| 1 | WS | NW |
| 2 | WS | Not funded |
| 2 | WS | Not funded |
| 2 | WS | Not funded |
| 3 | NW | NW |
| 3 | AR | NW |
| 3 | AR | NW |
| 4 | AR | Not funded |
| 4 | AR | Not funded |
| 4 | WS | Not funded |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUMPRODUCT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$13=A2)*--($B$2:$B$13="NW")),"NW","Not Funded")
```

---

Or, Using `COUNTIFS()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,A2,$B$2:$B$13,"NW"),"NW","Not Funded")
```

---

Or, If you want a spill array formula then use `MAP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=MAP(
    A2:A13,
    B2:B13,
    LAMBDA(x, y,
        IF(
            COUNTIFS(
                x:A2, x,
                y:B2, "NW"
            ),
            "NW",
            "Not Funded"
        )
    )
)
```

---